# Trouble using pre-trained model from niftynet

Tags: deep-learning, transfer-learning, niftynet

I want to do a 2 class segmentation using `dense_vnet` model available on niftynet which originally does a 9 class segmentation

I tried to retrain only the last layer by making changes in config file according to this suggestion: [HOw to fine tune niftynet pre trained model for custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664571/how-to-fine-tune-niftynet-pre-trained-model-for-custom-data)

```
vars_to_restore = ^((?!DenseVNet\/(skip_conv|fin_conv)).)*$

num_classes = 2
```

error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Assign
> requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [2] rhs shape=
> [9]
> [[{{node save/Assign_8}} = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, *class=["loc:@DenseVNet/conv/conv*/b"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true,
> *device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](DenseVNet/conv/conv*/b,
> save/RestoreV2:8)]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have restored too many layers, some of them are still designed to classify to 9 classes. Inspect the architecture and exclude restore for all layers which are designed to classify into 9 classes.